# Views Infinite Scroll - Back Button Behaviour

Tags: 7

I recently integrated the Views Infinite Scroll module which integrates the jquery autopager library with Drupal Views. You may see the result [here](http://mygadgeto.com).

The problem I am facing is related to the url. Every time a new set of data is loaded the pager integer is increased. Upon clicking on a product and then clicking your browser's "back" button, the browser keeps the page hash and load the content that was being viewed before.

The issue with that is that no previous loaded content shows up. The data set starts from the page number.

Any help is appreciated